# jQuery dataTable set page limit for specific bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatable

I have three, four and sometimes five tables in the same page but most of them are in modal dialogs.
What happens is that I want the tables which are not in modal dialogs to display 10 items per page and those who are in modal dialogs I want them to display on 3.

You can view an [working example in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tyg33z4z/1/).

I initialize my settings (by default) with the following parameters:

```
var settings = {
        "bPaginate": true,
            "bLengthChange": false,
            "bInfo": true,
            "bAutoWidth": false,
            'aoColumnDefs': [{
            'bSortable': false,
                'aTargets': ['nosorting']
        }],
            'order': [
            [0, 'DESC']
        ]
    }
```

Which by default put 10 records as limit per page.
After that I need to verify if the table belongs to a modal and if so, add a property name 'pageLength' to specify the limit.

```
if ($(this).closest('.fade').length > 0) {
    settings.push({
       "pageLength": 3
    });
}
```

I believe that one of the problems is because settings isn't actually an array of objects, to be I should instead have something like:
var settings = [];

```
settings.push({bPaginate: true, bLengthChange: false}); // etc
// or
settings.push({"bPaginate": true, "bLengthChange: false"}); // etc
```

But if I use  this method, the dataTable won't recognize it when I add this variable to the plugin.

```
$('.dataTable').dataTable(settings);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/hcqv2m3m/2/). It loops all tables and create them one by one with correct settings.

Settings in an js object. You can simply overrule it like settings.pageLength.

```
if ($('.dataTable').length > 0) {
    var settings = {
        "bPaginate": true,
            "bLengthChange": false,
            "bInfo": true,
            "bAutoWidth": false,
            'aoColumnDefs': [{
            'bSortable': false,
                'aTargets': ['nosorting']
        }],
            'order': [
            [0, 'DESC']
        ]
    }
    $('.dataTable').each(function () {

        if ($(this).closest('.fade').length > 0) {
            settings.pageLength = 3;
        }

        $(this).dataTable(settings);


    });

    $('.dataTables_filter').empty();

}
```

Comment: I've tried with a loop but I think I would never remember to try out `settings.pageLength` :D. Thank you!